# Definition of "discrete space"

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to understand the definition of "discrete space"

$\mathbb N$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb R$.

Let $1/\mathbb N=\{1,1/2,1/3,...,1/n...\}$.

Is $1/\mathbb N$ also a discrete subset of $\mathbb R$?

---

Here is my clue: I think the space $1/\mathbb N$ is also discrete. And since $\{0\}$ is singleton, then, $1/\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$ is a discrete.

But here comes my confusions: in a discrete space, any converging sequence should terminate with a number: this mean that, if sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$, then, there exists $m$ such that for all $n>m$, $x_n=x$.

This definition works for $\mathbb N$. But obviously does not work for $\{0\}\cup 1/\mathbb N$, as sequence $1/n$ does not terminate at $0$.

Comment: Please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). What is your opinon about this question and why? To begin with, what are your definition of "[discrete space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space)" (there are many equivalent definitions), and of the [natural topology of your subset "$1/\Bbb N$" of $\Bbb R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology)?

Comment: Or from a higher point of view: the homeomorphism $\Bbb R^*\to\Bbb R^*,x\mapsto1/x$ maps $\Bbb N$ onto "$1/\Bbb N$" and $\Bbb N$ is a discrete (sub)space, hence so is  "$1/\Bbb N$".

Comment: For each $\frac1n$ choose a ball of radius  $0<r<\frac1n -\frac1{n+1}$ so that $B(\frac1n , r) \cap 1/\mathbb{N} = \{\frac1n\}$. Try to generalize this using separability instead of a metric argument using balls.

Comment: @AnneBauval This is what I think and I agree with you. However, it seems like in a discrete space, any sequence must terminate at one of the points in the space. However, here in $1/\mathbb N$, the sequence $1/n$ does not terminate at any point.

Comment: By "terminate at" you probably mean "converge to". But your claim is false. For instance in the discrete space $\{-1,1\},$ the sequence $(-1)^n$ does not converge. That said, to avoid the closure of your post for "low quality" by "lack of context", you should improve it as indicated in my first comment.

Comment: @AnneBauval OK, I added the clue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you wrote is correct except "And since $\{0\}$ is singleton, then, $1/\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$ is a discrete."

$1/\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$ is not discrete, as you proved, but $1/\mathbb N$ is. You can prove it either starting from scratch, using your prefered [definition of "discrete space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) (there are many equivalent definitions), and of the natural [topology of your subset $1/\Bbb N$ of $\Bbb R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology), or, from a higher point of view, by simply noting that the *homeomorphism*
$$\Bbb R^*→\Bbb R^*,\quad x↦1/x$$
maps the discrete (sub)space $\Bbb N$
onto $1/\Bbb N.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $1/\mathbb N$ is also discrete. This refers to the discrete topology, so you can read about that if you want,  but for subsets $S \subset\mathbb R$ it boils down to this question: for every element $s\in S$, is there an open set that contains $s$ and no other elements of $S$?

The answer to this question is yes for $\mathbb N$, $1/\mathbb N$, $\mathbb Z$, or finite sets like $\{0, \pi, 1/5\}$, so these are discrete sets. The answer is no for $\mathbb Q$ or for intervals $[a,b]$, so these are indiscrete.

Specific to your example, letting $1/n \in 1/\mathbb N$. The "nearest neighbor" of this point in the set $1/\mathbb N$ is $1/(n+1)$ and the distance between them is $$\frac 1 n - \frac 1 {n+1} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)} > \frac 1 {(n+1)^2}.$$ This means that the interval $$I_n = \left(\frac 1 n - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}, \frac 1 n + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)$$ contains the point $1/n$ and no other point in the set $1/\mathbb N$. The existence of such intervals for all point $1/n$ shows that $1/\mathbb N$ is discrete.